# Deserialize json to subtypes with complex constructor Kotlin + Jackson

Tags: java, json, kotlin, serialization, jackson

I am using kotlin and jackson and I am looking for a way to deserialize json with the following structure, that can vary between two cases:

Case 1:

```
{
    "parent1": "parentvalue1",
    "parent2": "parentvalue2",
    "child1": "childvalue1",
    "child2": "childvalue2"
}
```

Case 2:

```
{
    "parent1": "parentvalue1",
    "parent2": "parentvalue2",
    "child3": "childvalue3",
    "child4": "childvalue4"
}
```

My Model classes look as follows:

Parent:

```
open class Parent(
    val parent1: String,
    val parent2: String
) {
    constructor (parent: Parent) : this(
        parent1 = parent.parent1,
        parent2 = parent.parent2
    )
}
```

Children:

```
class Child1(
    parent: Parent,
    val child1: String,
    val child2: String
) : Parent(parent)

class Child2(
    parent: Parent,
    val child3: String,
    val child4: String
) : Parent(parent)
```

Is it doable to deserialize such structure using Jackson?

```
val parent = ObjectMapper().readValue(myJson, Parent::class.java)
```

Comment: Try [this guide](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-in-kotlin-with-jackson/). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hello @AliasCartellano, thank you for your answer.

Mentioned guide does not cover inheritance - my case is not bidirectional relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of things missing. First you will need to declare the constructor to use when deserializing the JSON, the ones that you have do not match JSON format:

```kotlin
class Child1(
    parent: Parent,
    val child1: String,
    val child2: String
) : Parent(parent) {
  
  @JsonCreator constructor (parent1: String, parent2: String, child1: String, child2: String) {
      super(parent1, parent2)
      child1 = child1
      child2 = child2
  )
}
```

Then, you also need to tell Jackson how to differentiate between `Child1` and `Child2`. You can do it as follows:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
  property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes(
  JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child1::class, name = "child1"), 
  JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child2::class, name = "child2") 
)
open class Parent(
    val parent1: String,
    val parent2: String
) {
    constructor (parent: Parent) : this(
        parent1 = parent.parent1,
        parent2 = parent.parent2
    )
}
```

In your case, you can even use the following given that the fields in the subtypes are different between them and thus Jackson can infer which subtype it is:

```kotlin
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes(
  JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child1::class, name = "child1"), 
  JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child2::class, name = "child2") 
)
open class Parent(
    val parent1: String,
    val parent2: String
) {
    constructor (parent: Parent) : this(
        parent1 = parent.parent1,
        parent2 = parent.parent2
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution introduces problem that I am trying to avoid - having 20 children, I need to copy 20 times parameters of Parent (parent1, parent2) into children's constructor, and if there is a need to introduce a new parameter in Parent, I will need to add it in 20 places as well.

Comment: That is true, but I am not sure if you can avoid it. Maybe you can try a custom deserializer, but I would say that it is not prettier than this.

Comment: If there was a way to access original value by some annotation I think it would be possible:

`@JsonCreator 
constructor(@JsonProperty child1: String, @JsonProperty child2: String, @JsonParentTypeSomehow(like original value)
parent: Parent)`

Comment: Additionally, it seems there is a feature in Jackson that allows you to avoid having the `type` property to handle subtypes: `@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.DEDUCTION)`. Never used it, but it seems it works if the fields in the subtypes are different between them and thus Jackson can infer which subtype it is.